# Error when running hyperopt fmin function (TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence)

Tags: python, dictionary, hyperopt

So I am using hyperopt, the fmin function to optimize hyperparameters. However, for some reason I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

The code I have is like this:

```
    fn = partial(self.loss_fn, x, y, metric, cv)
    best = fmin(
        fn=fn,
        space=self.params[self.model.__class__.__name__],
        algo=tpe.suggest,
        max_evals=len(self.trials) + 10,
        trials=self.trials,
    )
    self.model.set_params(best.params)

def loss_fn(self, x, y, metric, cv, params):
    print(params)
    print(self.model.__class__.__name__)
    self.model.set_params(**params)
    return -cross_val_score(self.model, x, y, scoring=make_scorer(metric), cv=cv)
```

Strangely, when I run it like this manually, it works fine:

```
print(fn({"C": 1.0, "gamma": 0.1}))
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out myself. `cross_val_score` returns a list of values, not a single value.